AWS Sagemaker endpoint's response parsing
I need to invoke a function to parse a text returned by an endpoint as a response in AWS.
I have successfully hosted an ASR model on an AWS SageMaker endpoint. Since I'm new to AWS, I'd like to inquire about the best method for parsing a response returned by the endpoint. My goal is to have a Python script in the cloud that processes the response, which is in text format, and then extracts only the final response. Maybe there is a way to change response generation and invoke my script on it and then return by endpoint such as creating custom Docker container for endpoint. I would appreciate any guidance or suggested approaches.

As you're not mentioning what kind of endpoint you're using, I assume that you deployed your model on an endpoint for real-time inference.
You can learn more about the different model deployment options here. Be aware of the limits imposed by a real-time inference endpoint:

To parse a the response from a real-time endpoint in Python, you can use the boto3 library. You can find a general step-by-step example in the AWS documentation.
For the specifics of an ASR model, you can find more information in this blog post which also walks through different deployment options.

Yes, I have deployed my model on an endpoint for real-time inference. But my problem is not about that, it is about parsing the response returned by the endpoint.
